# Load all views upfront

Tags: durandal

I have an app with Knockout binded views. It loads all HTML upfront, to minimize requests to the server.

I want to introduce Durandal to the app. Is this scenario supported? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us some more information?

This scenario is possible, as there nothing which would prevent you from loading your own HTML and binding it with knockout.

You will, however, NOT be able to do this in a way that meets the standards and conventions of this framework.

If you have many html views, my suggestion would be to create a small program which converts these existing views and view-models into their Durandal analogues. It will save you loads of headaches later.

[Creating a View](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-View/)